# Access EA Repository from Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, enterprise-architect

I would like to access EA repository from Windows Service.
The goal is to get all latest changes of Version Control, behind the scenes.

When I try the following :

```
EA.Repository repository = new EA.RepositoryClass();
```

I get this error:

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXX}   
failed due to the following error: 80080005."
```

-where XXX is GUID of EA.Repository in registry.

In my searches for solution, I found that changing the COM object properties may solve the problem. Navigating to Windows DCOM Config, there is no EA.App object in list.

Any ideas? Any other solution? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It does not work as service. EA needs a logged on user. Search the EA forum (though it's a PITA).

Comment: Is there no workaround for it. I have found this tutorial: http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2009/09/16/running-enterprise-architect-on-a-server/

Comment: @cremersstijn, Thanks. I highly appreciate it.